# How to display referenced field data in view?

Tags: 8, views

I have two content types named as "abc" and "xyz" respectively.

"xyz" content type having field called "field_abc". 
Its a referenced field to "abc" content type.

I create a view by taking "abc" contents. 
Is it possible to show the title of "xyz" in which "abc" taken as referenced field?

I think the reverse may works. Means if I create a view by taking "xyz" contents. But i need to know if I create a view by taking "abc" contents. It will work on not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a backreference. For D8 this is an open feature request:

[Implement Entity Reference Backreferences](https://www.drupal.org/node/2497649)

You should consider to this is in a forward reference (what you call reverse). Because even if the feature Backreferences is available, you would also somehow need to manage that there is only one reference, which you want to get the title field from. You can control this in the forward direction by making the reference field single value, but not in the other direction.